# Oracle APEX 20.1 :Unable to Import Applications

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.1

I have APEX 20.1 (recently upgraded from 19.1) on an On-premise DB. I am trying to import application using Export/Import Utility in Page designer. After dropping the application file to be imported into the file browse area, and on click of next I get the below error

[image]

Configuration Details:

TOMCAT+ORDS

Help me fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced this, and the only workaround I've found is to import via the command line, and ensure I generate an offset before importing the application.

```
exec APEX_APPLICATION_INSTALL.GENERATE_OFFSET;
```